# DJANGO:How to perform AND operation for my query?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

There are  two models .I want to make query to extract only the app exact app related `Adspaces` .

## models.py

```
class Appname(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='appname', null=True, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
     name=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False,help_text='Add your new App') 
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("dashapp:space",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Adspace(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='adspace', null=True, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
     ad_space=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False) 
     app=models.ForeignKey('Appname', related_name='appnames',default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     PID_TYPE = (
    ('FN','FORMAT_NATIVE'),
    ('FNB','FORMAT_NATIVE_BANNER'),
    ('FI','FORMAT_INTERSTITIAL'),
    ('FB','FORMAT_BANNER'),
    ('FMR','FORMAT_MEDIUM,RECT'),
    ('FRV','FORMAT_REWARDED_VIDEO'),
)
    format_type=models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=PID_TYPE,default='FN',blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.ad_space
    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("dashapp:create",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

## Views.py

## SHowing the one where i need to the query

```
      class spacelist(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
              model=Adspace
              template_name='adspace_list.html'
              def get_queryset(self):
                       query_set=super().get_queryset()
                       return query_set.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Here I need to perform One more query so that EACH APP show their own adspaces when clicked right now every app show every show adspaces.
I have the idea what to do as if i compare app_id then it'll show the exact app related adspaces, but i dont know how to write query for the same as i already have one query present.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

From what I understand you are trying to filter both on the app_id and the request user at the same time, so you could try look something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

...
def get_queryset(self):
    query_set=super().get_queryset()
    return query_set.filter(Q(user=self.request.user) & Q(app_id=app_id))
...
```

This lets you do a single filter with both your requirements at the same time (i.e. retrieve the `Adspace` instances for a specific `user` with a specific `Appname`).

Comment: I was able to extract the exact data. It helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You chain another `filter` at the end like this:

```
class spacelist(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model=Adspace
    template_name='adspace_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = super().get_queryset()
        query_set = query_set.filter(user=self.request.user)
        app_id = [...]
        return query_set.filter(app_id=app_id)
```

The problem left is to find out what is the `app_id` coming from. How do you know what is the current app? Several options here.

## Option 1: From the request

It can come from the current user: `self.request.user.appname.all()` but that will give you multiple apps, if the user can only have one app, you should change your model `Appname.user` to a `OneToOneField`.

Otherwise, I suggest changing your `related_name='appnames'` to reflect the multiplicity in the reverse relationship.

## Option 2: From the URL

It can come from the URL, your space list view should extract an `app_id` parameter from the URL where it's defined:

```
url(r'^(?P<app_id>[0-9]+)/spaces/$', spacelist.as_view(), name='space_list'),
```

And then in the spacelist view, you would get this parameter like this:

```
app_id = self.kwargs['app_id']
return query_set.filter(app_id=app_id)
```

Hope that helps

**UPDATE:**

Also worth noting that QuerySets [are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), meaning the result will get evaluated as late as possible by Django. Therefore, when you call:

```
query_set = query_set.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

The Django ORM doesn't execute any DB queries yet, and you can chain more filters after that:

```
query_set = query_set.filter(user=self.request.user)
query_set = query_set.filter(app_id=app_id)
```

Which behind the scenes is extending the query that *will* be executed when required. But at this point, no query is actually run. To see the query that will get executed you can print out the `query` attribute of the QuerySet:

```
print(query_set.query)
```

Which should log something like:

```
SELECT "app_adspace"."user_id" ... 
FROM 
  "app_adspace" 
WHERE 
  "app_adspace"."user_id" = 1234 AND "app_adspace"."app_id" = 5678
```

Comment: The flow is like this step 1: I  go to the homepage which consist of list of a Appname I have made                STEP 2: Each app contains a list which takes me to the list of adsapces and the url contains `app_id` when im in going to the adspace page.So  now as i have to differentiate each logged in user data separately , I also have to separate  each adspace which i created for particular appname

Comment: I need to apply both the query , DO you have any idea how to do apply both of them at once?

Comment: When chain querysets, they are only applied once, because querysets are lazy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy